# how to unpack SAP oracle installation files in linux system

Tags: linux, archive

I am installing `SAP DB` in Linux system, i have already downloaded and moved the files to required directories. I am unpacking the archive with this command:
`unrar x 5104xxxx_part1.exe`

After the extraction all the extracted files are inaccessible(no `rwx`) since the directory to which the files need to be extracted is getting created at the end of extraction. I have tried creating the directory manually before extraction, but the directory is getting removed and recreated at the end of extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I Couldn't extract the files in linux properly, So i moved the files on to a windows system and ran the executable rar file there. After unpacking i moved the unpacked files back to linux system.